# Set properties before awakeFromNib fires

Tags: swift, xib, awakefromnib

I need to set a property of a `UIView` before `awakeFromNib` is fired.

This is what I tried:

```
if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyNib", owner: self, options: nil) as? [MyNib], 
views.count > 0 {
let v = views.first!
v.count = 78
// or
v.configureContent(n: 78)
return v...
```

`configureContent` gets called but after `awakeFromNib`, so I can't use the value of `count` inside the body of `awakeFromNib`.

I red [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1618147-loadnibnamed?language=swift) about the *options* parameter, but I'm not sure it can be of any help.

Another option would be to avoid any sort of *injection* and ask for data from some source directly from the `awakeFromNib`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` gets called before `awakeFromNib()`, so what about there?

Comment: ... also `didMoveToSuperview()` and some others...

Comment: @trojanfoe: if I move all my code to `init` (previously unused), the code crashing when I set the delegate for a UIScrollView (`scrollView.delegate=self`)

Comment: Do it later (in the lifecycle) then, like `didMoveToSuperview()`.

Comment: (anyway, if I print the value of count, it is 0, that's the default value, not the one I pass from outside)

Comment: @trojanfoe: in the context of my app, this could not be safe because the view is notified multiple times, even when I don't need the behavior contained in the `awakeFromNib` body. I can check if it has been removed (eg. `if let superview = self.superview {...)` but I can't imagine any other case when the superview changes (it is an MKAnnotationView)